Numpy 2 has a separate float64(nan) - how to get rid of it?
It appears that Numpy 2 introduced its own separate float64(nan) - different from np.nan. Now regression tests fail because while
>>> np.nan is np.nan
True

we now have
>>> np.nan is np.float64("nan")
False

(also json cannot serialize those new NaNs).
Why did they make this change?
Is there a way to cast numpy floats to normal floats automatically?

Numpy raise an error on my machine because np.float is obsolete: "np.float was a deprecated alias for the builtin float. To avoid this error in existing code, use float by itself. Doing this will not modify any behavior and is safe. If you specifically wanted the numpy scalar type, use np.float64 here. The aliases was originally deprecated in NumPy 1.20; for more details and guidance see the original release note at: https://numpy.org/devdocs/release/1.20.0-notes.html#deprecations" . Using np.float is especially not great here since 32-bit NaN and 64-bit ones are different.

@JérômeRichard- thank you, I fixed the typo

What change? I get False with NumPy 1 as well.

np.nan is of type float which is a bit surprising (not a Numpy type). Thus it will not be the same than np.float32("nan") or np.float64("nan"). However, strangely, np.nan is float("nan") is not true either... Maybe the Python NaN are signalling NaN while Numpy ones are quiet NaN? Note that comparing NaN is generally a very bad idea. Indeed, a NaN is never equal to itself and there are many different NaN (even quiet NaNs). It is better to use np.isnan. Btw, I also get False with Numpy 1.24.3 (on Windows).

@JérômeRichard: There's no reason for float("nan") to return the particular object numpy.nan. You'd see the same if you tried 2.0 is float("2.0")

@user2357112 Oh right indeed, a new object can be created. Thank you. It would be equal if the value was somehow cached (AFAIK other languages like Java does that for small integers and certainly for NaN, which impact some Python implementations but apparently not CPython). Maybe the benefit is rather small.

There are several NaNs (see below and NaN as reference) and python can reuse objects or not. Using X is Y as part of a unit test is the core issue here.
For example np.inf - np.inf yields np.nan:
np.inf-np.inf
# nan

And yet:
np.nan is (np.inf-np.inf)
# False

If you want to know if an object is NaN, always use np.isnan (or the math or pandas equivalent), never object comparisons or is:
np.isnan((np.inf-np.inf))
# True

more on NaNs and python objects
NaNs are not encoded in a single way. There can be quiet NaNs (ambiguous operation) or signalling NaNs (erroneous operation). In addition, python can reuse objects… or not.
When running np.nan is np.nan python uses the same object for both, if you're running np.log(-1) is np.log(-1) on my machine, this creates two different objects and the result is False:
np.log(-1) is np.log(-1)
# False

To give you a more complex example, on my machine np.nan always gives the same object. Quiet/signalling NaNs always produce different objects. Successively producing one type of NaN seems to sometimes reuse the object, sometimes not:
(id(np.nan),        # 135051355677520
 id(np.inf-np.inf), # 135046756258928
 id(float('nan')),  # 135046756258928
 id(np.log(-1)),    # 135046756256624  # triggers warning
 id(np.sqrt(-1)),   # 135046756256624  # triggers warning # same as previous
 id(float('nan')),  # 135046756258928                     # same as before
 id(np.sqrt(-1)),   # 135046756261584  # triggers warning # different
 id(np.nan),        # 135051355677520                     # same as before
)

Running it again, all ids change, but with the same pattern. np.nan remains stable:
(id(np.nan),        # 135051355677520
 id(np.inf-np.inf), # 135046756261872
 id(float('nan')),  # 135046756261872
 id(np.log(-1)),    # 135046756262736  # triggers warning
 id(np.sqrt(-1)),   # 135046756262736  # triggers warning # same as previous
 id(float('nan')),  # 135046756261872                     # same as before
 id(np.sqrt(-1)),   # 135046756262640  # triggers warning # different
 id(np.nan),        # 135051355677520                     # same as before
)

In short, don't do this. Use np.isnan

The id output differences you're seeing don't have anything to do with quiet/signaling NaNs or other NaN encoding differences. np.nan is kept alive by the reference in numpy.__dict__ (and other references), so its ID can't be reused for other objects. np.inf-np.inf and float('nan') both create new floats, and the first one dies before the second is created, so they happen to be allocated in the same memory location.

np.log(-1) and np.sqrt(-1) both create new instances of numpy.float64 rather than float. The allocator happens to allocate them in the same location as each other, but a different location from the ordinary float created by np.inf-np.inf and float('nan').

@user2357112 my point was that it's both, NaNs can be encoded differently and can also be reused as the same object… or not (as classical in python).

You should probably clarify that, then, because your answer's current wording implies that the id snippet is supposed to be giving an example of encoding differences.

Fair enough, I'll clarify

@user2357112 I hope this is better now. As you can see quiet or signalling NaNs can be reused if produced successively, but a quiet NaN will never be the same object as a signalling NaN.

You don't show object reuse, you just show memory reuse.

...but you don't have signaling NaNs here. The warnings don't come from signaling NaNs - NumPy detects IEEE 754 floating point exceptions to produce those warnings. You'd see a similar warning with np.exp(10000), even though there's no such thing as a "signaling infinity".

@user2357112 My bad, I checked the binary representation and both are indeed quiet NaNs (11111111110000000000000000000000). I know the warning is triggered by python itself but I really though different NaNs were returned. I'll try to find where I had read this. Of note, the type of NaN is not the same, np.inf-np.inf is a float, np.sqrt(-1) is a np.float64. The important message remains that one shouldn't use == or is to compare NaNs.
